# $b^{r+s}=b^r b^s$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3e, page 22, problem 6b.

> Fix $b>1$. Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^r b^s$, where $r$ and $s$ are rational numbers.

Below is the solution to the above problem taken from [this link](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Rudin/Rudin_1.pdf). Unfortunately, I don't understand how it is justified to write that $b^{mq+np}=b^{mq}b^{np}$. I'd appreciate a clarification.

[image]

Comment: The additive property of exponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is justified because $mq, np$ are both integers.  We assume that we know $b^{r+s}=b^rb^s$ already, for $r,s$ integers.

Comment: Oh I see... I didn't know that we could assume this.

Answer (score 0):

For integers, $b^n$ is defined as $b\cdot b\cdots b$, where there are $n$ $b$s. Using that multiplication is associative, one can prove the additive property of exponents, which allows you to conclude what you wish to.